# java.lang.NullPointerException; Trying to create an object and call some methods

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to create a object that holds 3 variables, and be able to run it through two different methods. This is my object. Based on the three variables, a, b and c, it holds the values for a line ax+by+c = 0.

```
public class APLine {

  private double a;
  private double b;
  private double c;

  //this method returns the slope of the line
  public double getSlope() { 
    double slope = (-a/b);
    return slope;
  }

  //this method checks to see if the line crosses the given point
  public boolean isOnLine(double x, double y) {
    if (a*x + b*y + c == 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  //constructor
  public APLine(double a, double b, double c) {
  }
}
```

And this is the test class I created to try my methods. I had no issues with compiling either class.

```
public class linetest {
  public void main (String[] args) {
    APLine l = new APLine(3, 5, 4.5);
    System.out.println(l.getSlope());
    System.out.println(l.isOnLine(0, 0));
    System.out.println(l.isOnLine(0, (-4.5/3)));
  }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you post the complete constructor? you seem to have not assigned any values to your member variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main method signature is incorrect, it should always be this:

**`public static void main(String[] args) { ... }`**

Also, your `APLine` constructor doesn't do anything with the parameters you pass. You should assign your instance variables to those parameters:

```
public APLine(double a, double b, double c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b; 
    this.c = c;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm fairly new to coding, so I don't always catch the little mistakes. It's working as should be now.